# Why do I keep getting 0.06 with WorkingPrecision->1?

Tags: random, arbitrary-precision

I'm trying to generate a list of 1000 random numbers with WorkingPrecision->1. Is there any particular reason that I'm getting some entries as 0.06?

I have tested the following lines:

```
X=RandomReal[UniformDistribution[],1000,WorkingPrecision->1]
```

or

```
X=RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[],1000,WorkingPrecision->1]
```

Is there a way to omit 0.06 and get true 1 precision, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`WorkingPrecision` is really more meant for setting the internal number precision while calculating your result. If you want a random number with one floating point digit you're probably better off with

```
Round[#, 0.1] & /@ RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[], 1000]
```

or

```
1/10 RandomInteger[{0, 10}, 1000] // N
```

or you can also set the precision or accuracy explicitly

```
SetPrecision[#, 1] & /@ RandomReal[{0,1}, 1000]
SetAccuracy[#, 2] &  /@ RandomReal[{0,1}, 1000]
```

**Edit:**
Like Mr.Wizard says, `SetPrecision` and `SetAccuracy` have a similar problem than your original solution, even though they are changing the precision after the calculation, because they have to decide how many *binary* digits to grant to the internal representation of the number. That's why this won't give a satisfying decimal representation in all cases. The other methods are safer in that regard.

Comment: Thies, that last method has the same problem as the OP's method; take a look at it.

Comment: What about : `N[Rationalize[RandomReal[UniformDistribution[], 1000], 0.1], 1]` ?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: yeah, now i see, that it's not optimal. `SetAccuracy[#, 2] &` is a bit better but still suffers from the binary representation.

Comment: I voted for your post because it answers the practical.  If you feel that my assertion about binary representation is correct, will you vote for mine?  Or suggest how I may improve it?

Comment: sure, thanks for the binary representation hint!

Answer (score 4):

I believe your problem is the result of the numbers' internal binary representation.

Consider this:

```
Tuples[{0, 1}, 3]

FromDigits[{#, -1}, 2] & /@ %

SetPrecision[%, 1]
```

> ```
> {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 1}}
>
> {0, 1/16, 1/8, 3/16, 1/4, 5/16, 3/8, 7/16}
>
> {0, 0.06, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.4, 0.4}
> ```

Comment: Yep, I was also trying to understand where the 0.06 came from, and if you try `InputForm /@ 
 Union[RandomReal[UniformDistribution[], 1000, WorkingPrecision -> 1]]` you will see the actual real numbers you get, and all are fractions of 16.